# Issue with adding a function to the .profile

Tags: bash, command-line

I added the following to the `~/.profile`:

```
#Change desktop background f(x)
function changeBackground() {
    FILE="'file://$(readlink -f "$1")'"
    echo changing to "$FILE"
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$FILE"
}
```

**Side Note**: The purpose of the function is for the user to specific a path to an image file and the function takes that image file and makes it the desktop background. Example: `changeBackground /backgrounds/background.png`

Then I ran, `export -f changeBackground` and I get the following error:

`./scripts/bins: line 15: export: changeBackground: not a function`

Why?

Comment: Did you `source ~/.profile` before running `./script/bins` so the function has actually been created?

Comment: Your quoting is over-zealous. You want `FILE="file://$(readlink -f "$1")"` -- otherwise you're sending literal single quotes to gsettings which I don't think you want.

Comment: @glennjackman No I didn't run `source ~/.profile` didn't realize I had too. Thanks! That fixed it.